# Change color of debug console variable display

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I would like to change the grey color of the variables as displayed with

```
console.log(variable)
```

in the debug console (JS/TS). It *isn't* `debugConsole.infoForeground` or any of its siblings (discussed in many SO questions), those govern the simple log outputs, not this live, tree-like display of an object. None of the other panel, sideBar and other theme colors seem to influence it, either. I'm not looking for various ANSI solutions to provide my own coloring, just to change the looks of the original display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As luck would have it, I immediately found it *after* having asked. Here's the reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#new-debug-theme-colors